# Abstract representation of a locally compact topological group which is not topological

Tags: representation-theory, topological-groups, locally-compact-groups

Let $G$ be a locally compact topological group, and $V$ be a locally convex topological vector space over $\mathbb{C}$. An *abstract* representation of $G$ is a homomorphism $\rho\colon G\rightarrow \text{Aut}(V)$. We call $\rho$ a *topological* representation if additionally, the map $G\times V\rightarrow V$ which takes $(g,x)\mapsto \rho_g(X)$ is continuous with respect to the product topology on $G\times V$.

Following the book "Fourier Analysis on Number Fields" by Ramakrishnan and Valenza, I've seen some nice results which characterize when an abstract representation is topological. However, I haven't been able to find (or come up with) any examples of abstract representations which are *not* topological! Are there any good examples of these?

Comment: $G=\Bbb{Z}_p^\times$ the units of the ring of $p$-adic integers and $\rho$ a field embedding $\Bbb{Q}_p\to \Bbb{C}$, which restrict to a non-continuous homomorphism $G\to \Bbb{C}^\times$.

Comment: To clarify, do you mean that the field embedding $\rho\colon \mathbb{Q}_p \hookrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ allows us to define a representation $\mathbb{Q}_p\rightarrow \text{Aut}(\mathbb{C})$ which takes a $p$-adic number to the inner automorphism which is conjugation by its image in $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: No. A group homomorphism $G\to \Bbb{C}^\times$ (a character, a 1-dimensional complex representation).

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies things. I think I've also worked out the details for why this representation isn't continuous. Consider the closed subset $\mathbb{Z}\subset \mathbb{C}$. The preimage of this closed set will be $\mathbb{Z}\subset \mathbb{Z}_p^\times$. We can show that $\mathbb{Z}\subset \mathbb{Z}_p$ is a proper dense subset, and we know that the only closed set which is dense in a topological space is the space itself. Thus, $\mathbb{Z}\subset \mathbb{Z}_p^\times$ cannot be closed, so the representation isn't continuous.

Comment: Yes, equivalently $\lim_{k\to \infty} 1+p^k$ converges to $1$ in $\Bbb{Z}_p^\times$ and its image in $\Bbb{C}^\times$ diverges to $+\infty$.